# Recording and later playing back DOM changes in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, testing, dom, selenium

**Background:**
We have web based product and a growing suite of automated Selenium tests which runs on a continuous integration system for every commit. Sometimes a test fails, and sometimes it's quite hard to find out what happened.

Previously we recorded and saved a video for every run (using recordMyDesktop), but this requires more CPU and disk space than we could spare.

**Question:**
Is there a Firefox plugin or a similar tool for recording DOM changes, and later visually playing them back, preferably on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We previously used recordMyDesktop on Ubuntu but also noticed it was too CPU intensive.

At [TestingBot](http://testingbot.com) (Cloud based Selenium Grid) we now use ffmpeg and x11grab which is a lot nicer CPU wise. It's also pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding an event listener on the dom modification events and then logging them along the lines of:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {someLoggingFunction(e);});
```

If you log the parent element of the node that the listener passes you should be able to playback any modifications.

Document Object Model Events: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html

---

It's not a timeline style playback put perhaps the Firediff extension for firebug:

http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firediff/

It can track all dom changes and allows for snapshots of the dom state to be saved out along with reverting through the history to previous states.

Comment: As you're stating, logging the changes could be done quite easily. It is the (visual) playback of the changes that is the tricky part. Building our own tool is an option, but not our preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a paid grid, but have you looked into [SauceLabs](http://saucelabs.com/)? They support screenshots and video playback of tests.

Comment: We've looked in to it briefly, but corporate policies stops us from publicly exposing or sending our code somewhere else, so this is sadly not an option at the moment.

Comment: SauceLabs has a Java tunnel called SauceConnect that secures all traffic and can run your tests in a private environment. You can read more at: http://saucelabs.com/docs/sauce-connect